# Creating a document in cloud firestore using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am having a lot of difficulty with a problem.

Using cloud_firestore on flutter, how can I create a new document in a collection (if it does not already exist), create a new document in that collection and create a new field in that document with a name, type of bool and a value of true?

This is what I have right now:

```
  await Firestore.instance
      .collection(collectionName)
      .document(documentName)
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
         // do something here

  });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a new document, you need to use `add()`:

```
  Firestore.instance.collection("users").add(
  {
    "name"    : "peter",
    "boolVal" : true
  }).then((value){
    print(value.documentID);
  });
```

`add()` will create a document with a random id, if you want to use your own id then use `setData()`:

```
  Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(id).setData(
  {
    "name" : "peter",
    "boolVal" : true
  }).then((value){
    print(value.documentID);
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Do you have a link to the documentation? I can't find a good reference to use for flutter

Comment: check my article https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/04/04/using-cloud-firestore-in-flutter/

Comment: Sure! Let me test it out and see how it works first